# Assign listener at onCreate time to subviews of dynamic loaded ListView items

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView managed by an ArrayList/ArrayAdapter.
The ListView item is defined in an XML layout file.

At initialisation time (onCreate) I load the ListView with a variable number of items and, at that moment, I need to assign a listener to one subview (a SeekBar) of each item.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
private String TAG = "MainActivity";

private ListView lv_controlli;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> hmControlli;
private ArrayList<String> controlli;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Init();
}

private void Init() {

    lv_controlli = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_Controls);

    hmControlli = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) hmControlli.put(String.valueOf(i), "Gruppo " + i);
    controlli = new ArrayList<String>(hmControlli.keySet());
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.control_layout, R.id.LBL_Controllo, controlli);
    lv_controlli.setAdapter(adapter);

    for (int i = 0; i < lv_controlli.getChildCount(); i++) {
        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) lv_controlli.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.SB_Intensita);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(valueOnChange);
    }

}

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener valueOnChange = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
    }
    ...
};

public void click(View view) {

    for (int i = 0; i < lv_controlli.getChildCount(); i++) {
        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) lv_controlli.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.SB_Intensita);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(valueOnChange);
    }

}
```

No listeners are assigned by Init() routine (called by onCreate()) because its execution happens when the ListView has not been already loaded, even though the adapter as been populated and assigned to the ListView.

The same kind of code works perfectly, instead, in the click() routine associated to a button that I press when the control is returned to the user.

So I can get the SeekBars actually usable only after my interaction and this is bad, of course.

Is there any point where the populated ListView is available before the control is returned to the user?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are good that the right way to solve this problem is not by trying to find a moment in time between `onCreate()` and when control of the app passes to the user, but by assigning your `OnSeekBarChangeListener` to the `SeekBar` inside your adapter.

You can create a subclass of `ArrayAdapter` that you use instead of the base `ArrayAdapter` implementation, then override `getView()` to add the listener. Something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.SB_Intensita);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(valueOnChange);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: If I understand your suggestion, this should be sort of a deferred association.

The listener would be linked to the element just before it becomes visible, isn't it?
Using this solution, are there any issues involved in the item life cycle I'd should take into account (i.e. multiple firings of getView)?

Comment: Ben's solution has worked and also, on implementing it, some aspect of the ListView behaviour has been clarified to me, expecially the need to save ListView source data somewhere because ListView, in general, doesn't provide rows for all the items of the arraylist used to build the adapter but just for about as many as the ones visible.
Thanks a lot.